# iOS Swift how to monitor UIViewController lifecyle

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development. So pardon me if this is a very basic thing.

From what I have learnt till now:

`UIViewController` class resembles somewhat equivalent to an `Activity` class in Android.

and `viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear` method to `onCreate/onStart` method

and `viewDidAppear` method to `onResume` method

Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Now, in `Android` we can monitor which of these methods(including other lifecycle methods) are triggered/called by implementing an `Interface` (`ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`) (somewhat resembling a protocol in iOS) which exists in the `Application` class in any Activity (particularly in a class which extends Application class).

It means that now these methods will be triggered/called whenever there is any navigation from one screen to another in the android app.

How do I do this in iOS using Swift? How do I know which screen(UIViewcontroller) the user is currently in and where he is navigating?

In short I want to write a standalone class which logs which screen(UIViewController) the user is currently in and which one of the lifecycle methods(viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear etc) is being executed?

Someone please help me out.

Edit:- I don't want them to subclass my standalone class instead of UIViewController class.

Answer (score 3):

There are no global events that are fired when the `UIViewController` lifecycle methods are called.  To create those you would need to subclass UIViewController as has been suggested.

You can look at `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController` to get the current root view controller (which is often, but not always the currently active view controller).

You wouldn't typically design an app that depended on some central object tracking the state of view controllers.

The flow of UIViewController methods is pretty well described in the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html) and you can also work it out from the function names -

- `viewDidLoad` called *after* the view controller instance is loaded (once per instantiation)
- `viewWillAppear` called *before* this view appears
- `viewDidAppear` called *after* this view appears
- `viewWillDisappear` called *before* this view disappears
- `viewDidDisappear` called *after* this view disappears

[image]

Comment: I will have a look into it

Comment: "There are no global events that are fired when navigation occurs". Indeed. But if you are using a `UINavigationController` instance, you can implement its delegate protocol and observe navigation events.

Comment: Well yes, but the question asks about UIViewController lifecycle.  Perhaps my use of the word "navigation" is slightly confusing.  Even the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods won't provide notification when the specific view controller lifecycle functions are called

Answer (score 1):

Create a view controller subclass and add that implementation in there. Then make sure all the view controllers you create subclass that new class rather than UIViewController itself

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am trying to find out another way to do it without having them to subclass my custom class. Any ideas?

Comment: I just feel that something could be done from in the AppDelegate class, but I really can't able to figure it out.

Comment: @OneStepBack it won't be possible from AppDelegate